# 'git pull' command faied:Permission denied

Tags: git

Error Message:

```
error: unable to write file .git/objects/pack/pack-92ef...e9d2.pack: Permission denied
fatal: cannot store pack file 
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried to delete all the files in the pack folder, but it failed. Still can't submit。

it makes me cannot pull and push.

How to solve it?
help!

Answer (score -1):

If you deleted all the files in your `.git/objects/pack` folder, you've very likely lost data.  Those files are used to store a compressed version of your Git data, and by deleting them, you've lost any data in that folder that isn't in another repository either on your computer or on a remote server.  If you have backups, you should use them now.

As for the reason you're getting this error, the message means that you don't have the proper permissions on that directory.  If you're on Linux, macOS, or another Unix system, you should make sure that you have read, write, and execute permissions on all of these directories: `.git`, `.git/objects`, and `.git/objects/pack`.  You should use `chmod` to change the permissions if need be.  If you're on Windows, you need to adjust the permissions appropriately for that operating system; its ACLs are much more complicated and there is not space to discuss it all here.